# In discord.py, the on_message does not trigger for one guild

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to figure out how to write a simple bot for Discord.
However, the problem I'm facing is that for one particular server (or guild as it is called), I don't get  any messages.

I am logged in this guild in the webinterface with the same user. And I see messages coming in.

However, in the client I do not see anything being logged.

The code is very simple:

```
import discord

class DiscordClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Connected as {self.user.display_name} to:")

        for guild in self.guilds:
            print(f"- {guild.name}")

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print(f"Message from '{message.guild.name}'")

DiscordClient().run(TOKEN, bot=False)
```

In the `on_ready`, I can see it knows the guild and even the channels. So that's fine. There is a connection...

The server is the "Among Us" server which has 500k users. So maybe it's a limitation because too much users? As the `on_message` does trigger correctly for servers with much more limited amount of users (like 20k or so).

What setting should I adjust to connect to this server in order to receive the messages?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but does your bot have permission to read messages on the large server?

Comment: @ZeroKnight: no, but that's also why I'm currently logging in with my own user (bot=False) instead of as a bot. And my own user does receive the messages just fine in the web interface...

Comment: I'm really not sure what to suggest in particular, since user accounts have different API access that I'm not sure is even documented. I wouldn't be surprised if that alone is the cause of the difference you're seeing here. Are you self-botting just to test the difference, or are you intending to write a self-bot?

Comment: I am writing a self-bot for the moment because it's easier to compare the differences down to the network level. What I noticed is that the json sent on the browser is different from the one discord.py sends, but for all intents and purposes that shouldn't matter... I am getting messages from smaller guilds just fine.

Comment: For anyone reaching this discussion, this is a bug I opened: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/6340

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with your code tbh, maybe it's an intents issue (?), try enabling some basic intents

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()

DiscordClient(intents=intents).run(TOKEN, bot=False)
```

Comment: I checked the intents indeed before posting here, but all were set to True. Maybe that is a bit wide, but it works on the smaller server... Going to set it explicitly like you mentioned.

Comment: Nope, I started with none() and added intents on messages, guilds & webhooks. I got messages from the other guilds I joined, but not the big one... Completely at a loss here :(